# Django custom dictionary response

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am using Django rest framework and I have a view that returns information but in dictionary format.
Here is the model I have:

```
class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    height = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
```

I want to return the following response as dictionary where the `name` field is the key:

```
{
    "Alice Allen": {
        "age": 3,
        "height": 98
    },
    "Bob Brady": {
        "age": 4,
        "height": 105
    }
}
```

I know I can use the GenericAPIView and implement the logic in 'get' method (get the data and parse into a dictionary) but I wonder if there is another solution using Django serializers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using viewset, you can try to override the `list` method and customize the response:

```
class ChildViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(ChildViewSet, self).list(request, *args, **kwargs)
        response.data = {result.pop('name'): result for result in response.data}
        return response
```

Comment: it works though it is not really a ModelViewSet. Thanks

Comment: worked for me too. question: should I be using `ModelViewSet`?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to implement a serializer for your model and override `to_representation` method and return how you want the model to represent.

Example

```
class ChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = '__all__'

    def to_representation(self, instance):
       # Here instance is instance of your model
       # so you can build your dict however you like
       result = OrderedDict()
       result[instance.name] = {"age" : instance.age, "height" : instance.height}
       return result
```

> that's a problem since it will no longer be a dictionary. with this suggestion I will get: [ {"Alice": "age": 3, "height": 98 }, ... ]

Ah, for this, i would suggest to create a view like this:

```
class DictView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = Domain.objects.all()

    def _get_serialized_items(self, input):
       result = OrderedDict()

        for item in input:
            result[item.name] = {"age" : item.age, "height" : item.height}

        return result

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)

        if page is not None:
            return self.get_paginated_response(self._get_serialized_items(page))

        return Response(self._get_serialized_items(queryset))
```

Comment: that's a problem since it will no longer be a dictionary. with this suggestion I will get:
[
    {"Alice":
        "age": 3,
        "height": 98
    },
...
[

Comment: @nirnah updated my answer with suggestion to return dict instead of list like you'd like